# 2006 Nissan Titan making grinding vibration at 20 sec

Tags: nissan, vibration, titan

My Titan is making a grinding and vibrating sound near the steering column at every 20 seconds. It does not seem to be affected by stopping or going to, it just always makes this sound. Even when car is off.

I have a video of the sound if it is helpful for diagnosing

Comment: Grinding and vibrating when the vehicle is off is completely weird. Please pst that video of the sound.

Comment: Power steering pump? If you're low on PS fluid, you may start getting odd noises.